# Overleaf doesn't find citation in bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, citing

I'm pretty new to Latex, i would like to cite a paper.
I have `main.tex` and a `bib/mybib.bib` files.
In the main.tex I write
`\cite{papername}`
and at the bottom I have `\bibliography{bib/mybib}`

In the bib file I have

```
@misc{papername,
  doi = {...},
  url = {...},
  author = {...},
  publisher = {...},
  year = {...},
}
```

However I get:

"Citation 'papername' on page 1 undefined on input line 101."
You have cited something which is not included in your bibliography. Make sure that the citation (`\cite{...}`) has a corresponding key in your bibliography, and that both are spelled the same way.

and

There were undefined references. You have referenced something which has not yet been labelled. If you have labelled it already, make sure that what is written inside `\ref{...}` is the same as what is written inside `\label{...}`.

What am I doing wrong? Do I need to add some packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please post a minimum working example. For example, a .tex file with the minimum necessary packages needed to reproduce your problem.

In the pre-ample of your .tex file, you can manually write your bibliography with the following code

```
\begin{filecontents}{bibliography.bib}
@misc{papername,
  doi = {...},
  url = {...},
  author = {...},
  publisher = {...},
  year = {...},
}
\end{filecontents}
```

Now, if I use standard overleaf settings, I cannot reproduce your problem. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{filecontents}{bibliography.bib}
@misc{papername,
  doi = {...},
  url = {...},
  title = {A Treatise on Anonymity},
  author = {John Doe},
  publisher = {...},
  year = {2042},
}
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}

\citet{papername}

\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{bibliography}

\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

Comment: thanks, I added \usepackage[english]{babel} and 
\usepackage{natbib}, now it works.